# How to update row value automatically in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I update the row values automatically in cell ?
Please see below image
[image]

If I change the value of "1" to "12" I want the down arrow cells to follow from it but increment by 1 like the image below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write formula - =1 + A1 and drag it down to your limits.

change value 1 to any value, it will follow the increment as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the value `1` in your first image is cell `A1`, then yo7 can enter the followint formula into `A2`:

```
=A1 + 1
```

Then, copy this formula down the `A` column as far as you need.  Now when you change the value of `A1` to some other value, the whole column should update.